# magento - adding static block to invoice document

Tags: php, magento, block

I would like to add the content of a  Magento CMS static block to the invoice send to customer.  I created a static block called my_invoice_message.

How do I push the contents into invoice and place it?
the template is called /sales/order_new.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same syntax as for injecting it in a cms/page :

```
 {{block type="cms/block" block_id="id-of-your-block" }}
```